# in SQLite table-name.column-name is a valid expression, but raises "no such column" error

Tags: sqlite

I'm  trying to update the "score" column in table Candidate
from table "scores" with columns  candID centreID score
but query

```
INSERT INTO Candidate (score) VALUES (scores.score)
```

gives error in statement:

> no such column: scores.score

The SQLite schema expr suggests scores.score is  valid. SQL beginner very grateful for help.,

Comment: You need to join the tables

Comment: Thanks Juergen, I thought I had. Latest try seems OK but throws up syntax error near ". " dbSendQuery(db, "UPDATE  Candidate 
      SET Candidate.score = (SELECT Scores.response
      FROM Scores
      WHERE Candidate.candID = Scores.candID AND Candidate.centreID = Scores.centreID )")

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Candidate 
JOIN Scores ON Candidate.candID = Scores.candID 
           AND Candidate.centreID = Scores.centreID
SET Candidate.score = Scores.response
```